# Enviar variável do PHP para Shell Script

Tags: php, bash, shell

Tenho um arquivo `.sh` e ele tem variáveis que preciso receber do PHP, segue um exemplo:

```
//variavel 1 que preciso receber externamente
NAME=""
//variavel 2 que preciso receber externamente
DIR=""

tar -zcf $HOME.tar.gz $DIR
```

A chamada do arquivo por PHP séria assim:

```
shell_exec('sh arquivo.sh');
```

só preciso saber como enviar os dados das 2 variáveis.

---

Outra forma seria enviar o script todo direto pelo php via `shell_exec()`, como enviaria um *script* desse tipo?

(Isso não funciona):

```
shell_exec('VAR=tar -zcf teste.tar.gz teste/testeDir
if [ "$SUCCESS" == "0" ]; then
   echo "Sucesso!"
else
   echo "Sucesso!"
fi');
```

Comment: Não sei se ajuda, mas pelo próprio PHP você pode executar comandos do bash acrescentando variáveis e pegando o retorno, desta forma dispensaria a necessidade deste arquivo bash externo.

Comment: Só uma coisinha: JS é client-side! Não estou entendendo qual o motivo de envolver o JS nisso.

Comment: viajei, pensei em fazer com ajax, mas ia usar php do mesmo...

Comment: Cara isso não funciona? `echo "{$HOME}";` e `echo "{$DIR}";` ?

Comment: não entendi Ivan, como eu uso isso ? li algo sobre enviar a variavel desse jeito: $page = shell_exec('my_script.sh "{$var1}" "{$var2}"'); mas não sei se tá certo e não consigo pegar ela no sh

Comment: tipo assim: `NAME="$(ls -1)"`. `echo "{$NAME}"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Passe os dados através de argumentos, que podem ser lidos nos scripts bash através de $1, $2, etc. Seu script bash ficaria assim:

```
#!/bin/bash
NAME="$1"
DIR="$2"

tar -zcf $NAME.tar.gz $DIR
```

No PHP, informe os argumentos na respectiva ordem:

```
shell_exec('sh seu_script.sh nome_qualquer diretorio_qualquer');
```

Comment: tb não funcionou!

Comment: Ok, primeiro verifique se o problema está no script bash ou no PHP. Rodando no terminal, o script bash vai bem?

Comment: desculpa, acho q era cache, funcionou!

Comment: No PHP, tenha certeza de informar o caminho completo do script bash.

Comment: só tava com um problema na variavel do php q ficou assim $teste = 'teste2'; $saida = shell_exec('sh ../script.sh '.$teste);

Answer (score 1):

Ao executar a função [`shell_exec`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.shell-exec.php) é possível passar os valores de variáveis como argumentos ao comando que será executado:

```
$arquivo = "teste";
$dir = "testeDir";

$resultadoExec = shell_exec("sh script1.sh $arquivo $dir");

echo $resultadoExec;
```

Para receber as informações no arquivo `.sh` use as [variáveis especiais](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/othertypesv.html) `$1` e `$2`:

```
#!/bin/bash

arquivo=$1".tar.gz"
dir=$2

# Verifica se o script recebe os argumentos
if [ $# -ne 2 ] then
   echo "Atenção! É necessário informar o arquivo e diretório de destino!"
   echo "Exemplo: \n $0 <nomeArquivo> <diretorio>"
   exit
fi

tar -zcf $arquivo $dir
if [ $? -eq 0 ] then
   echo "Arquivo descompactado com sucesso no diretório: $dir"
else
   echo "Erro! Não foi possível realizar a operação! Tente novamente"
fi
```

Comment: não funcionou nem o php nem o sh

Comment: era cache, provalvemente está funcionando!

Answer (score 0):

No arquivo shell `script.sh` faça o seguinte:

```
#!/bin/bash

NAME='filename'
DIR='path'

echo $NAME
echo $DIR
tar -zcf $NAME.tar.gz $DIR
```

No PHP faça assim:

```
$file = "script.sh";
if (file_exists($file)) {
   chmod($file, "go+x");
   $string = shell_exec('sh '.$file);
   $data = explode("\n", $string);
   //Nome: filename - Diretório: path
   echo 'Nome: '. $data[0] . ' - Diretório: ' . $data[1]; 
} else {
  echo 'arquivo  não existe';
}
```

Se precisar passar parâmetros, no shell:

```
  #!/bin/bash

    NAME=$1
    DIR=$2

    echo $NAME
    echo $DIR
    tar -zcf $NAME.tar.gz $DIR
```

No PHP:

```
 $file = "script.sh";

   $params = array('filename', 'path');
   $param = ' '.implode(' ', $params);
    if (file_exists($file)) {
       chmod($file, "go+x");
       $string = shell_exec('sh '.$file.$param);
       $data = explode("\n", $string);
       //Nome: filename - Diretório: path
       echo 'Nome: '. $data[0] . ' - Diretório: ' . $data[1]; 
    } else {
      echo 'arquivo  não existe';
    }
```